# how to read ipconfig, how to figure out what's my ip address?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn

In my pc's network sharing center, there's wifi, ethernet, vpn, dial-up connection.

If I type `ipconfig` to checkout my ip address, it lists all kinds of address info separated by all kinds of adapters:
[image]
I'm totally confused:

If I want to see my ip address, how do I know which one is the correct one?
e.g. I'm using wifi and connect to vpn.

Comment: BTW, these are all internal ("private") IP addresses, and not the "public" IP address you'll be using after NAT (network address translation) to speak to the rest of the internet. Use `tracert` to see this address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several IP addresses – each connection has its own, of course, and *all* of them are "correct" depending on what you need them for.

While ipconfig might not explicitly tell you which address would be the 'main' one, looking for "Default gateway" is a good guess – especially when only one is listed. (`route print` might show more information, though.)

- The "PPP" adapter is likely to be your VPN connection (PPTP or PPPoE). Its IP addresses are `10.129.36.22` (IPv4, PtP, internal) and `fdeb:9fb2:4cb8:e47c::ac3` (IPv6, PtP, internal). It's also the only interface that lists a "default gateway", so it's likely going to be the 'default' address used when you connect somewhere.
- The "Wi-Fi" adapter describes the underlying wireless connection. Its IP address is `192.168.1.12` (IPv4, /24, internal). That's the address used to reach the VPN server *itself*.
- There are two *virtual* network interfaces created by VMware for use with virtual machines. One has the IP address `192.168.20.1`, the other has `192.168.195.1` (both IPv4, /24, and obviously internal).

Answer (score -1):

I will attempt to explain what all of that mumbo jumbo is, this way you will understand it. First off you IP address. Let me ask why you need thextra IP. By answering why you need it, then I will be able to give you the correct response. To explain.
Your actual IP address is dynamic which means it changes, this would be the IP address from your ISP to your home, kinda like your street address, but this one changes quite often. You could make it stay the same (static) but we will safe that for another day. You can find this address typically by looking in your router.rarely will you get it from ipconfig. Those IP addresses are the addresses if each device you have connected to your home network 192.168.1.1 would be Your access point (router)all the way up to 192.168.1.225 . The finstructions block of information appears to bleave your IP the 10.129.36.22 that most likely is the VPN IP address as I checked on my system and it shows the internal IP  the 192.168.1.1. All of those groups listed are adapters that allow different types of connections to opt Internet. For example the ETHERNET is when you plug directly into the modem. The LAN is a local area connection usually like a network within a network.

The ETHERNET VMWARE all that say VMWARE are adapters that is specific to VMWARE.

Your Wireless LAN wifi is your wifi connection.

The one that has BLUETOOTH in the name is your Bluetooth wireless adapter and is specific for that protocol.

The bottom ones that contain the TUNNEL are just that. Briefly, in order for IPV4 and IPV6  and some other, "protocols to work together the must tunnel through in order to make a secure connection.

As you become more familiar with making changes to your network, you will get to understand them better. You can also when feeling interested type them into your address bar and read the search results.

Also a simple way to find out the real IP address you on on is to type onto the address bar "what is my IP address" it will come up just verify the info. Like you ISP and so on.

I hope that helps you. I am on mobile so if there is bad spelling and grammar I apologize. It is a tiny screen. Lol

Comment: The 192.268.1.1 upto 255 are the IP address of your devices and your router will route traffic to each device. To find out what each devices address is, you can find that by accessing your router,

Answer (score -3):

IPv4 Adress : 192.168.1.12 <- the number is your ip

Comment: why? unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be the one you mentioned when I connected to VPN.